# Last users connected to the system

Tags: linux, bash, session, unix

Hello how to display the last sessions from all users connected to the system in linux (but that are not connected any more) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last -F | grep -v "still logged in" | cut -d " " -f1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using this `last` with `awk`:

```
last | awk 'NF>7 && !/still logged in/ && !seen[$1]++'
```

Answer (score 0):

The command for that is called `last` :-)

Answer (score -1):

Please try below command:

```
last | awk 'NF>7 && !/still logged in/ && !seen[$1]++' | cut -d " " -f1
```

Comment: -1: You basically copied @anubhava's answer and added a `cut` to the pipe which a) can be easily added to the `awk` code and b) isn't even what OP asked for (they didn't want the username(s) but the whole session information). Also, please format your code properly.